# JSHint doesn't like my indentation

Tags: javascript, indentation, jshint

When I run my build script, JSHint shows me the following error:

```
Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

app/module/monitoring.module/model/test.service.js
  line 8   col 13  Expected 'x' to have an indentation at 5 instead at 13.
  line 9   col 13  Expected 'y' to have an indentation at 5 instead at 13.
  line 10  col 9   Expected '}' to have an indentation at 1 instead at 9.

✖ 3 problems
```

Here is the code of this test file:

```
'use strict';

var foo = { 'bar': function () {} };
foo
    .bar(
        'a',
        {
            'x': 1,
            'y': 2
        },
        'b'
    );
```

If I run `jshint test.service.js` directly, no error is thrown. Here is my `.jshint`:

```
{
    "node": true,
    "browser": true,
    "esnext": true,
    "bitwise": false,
    "camelcase": true,
    "curly": false,
    "eqeqeq": false,
    "immed": true,
    "indent": 4,
    "latedef": true,
    "loopfunc": false,
    "newcap": true,
    "noarg": true,
    "quotmark": "single",
    "regexp": true,
    "undef": true,
    "unused": true,
    "strict": true,
    "trailing": true,
    "smarttabs": true,
    "boss": true,
    "globals": {
        "angular": false,
        "alert": false,
        "jQuery": false,
        "$": false,
        "d3": false,
        "_": false,
        "describe": false,
        "it": false,
        "expect": false,
        "kronosCharts": true,
        "moment": false,
        "OpenLayers": false
    }
}
```

But I think, none of these options should tell JSHint to not like my indentation. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

Because there are comments, that my indentation is not good and/or does violate standards, here is the real code. If you can tell me a good (or standard) way to make the indentation here, this would help me, too:

```
var webserviceRequest = webservice.createRequest();
webserviceRequest
    .addMethodRequest(
        'GetFilterItems',
        {
            'Start': start,
            'NumItems': numItems
        },
        function (items) {
            items = syncItems(items);
            callback(items);
        }
    )
    .send()
;
```

**EDIT 2**

This is, what JSHint tells me to do:

```
'use strict';

var foo = { 'bar': function () {} };
foo
    .bar(
        'a',
        {
    'x': 1,
    'y': 2
},
        'b'
    );
```

I'll write a bug report tomorrow...

Comment: I don't much like your indentation either, did you just put the object property on the next line ?

Comment: Why run your code through a coding standard checker if you want to ignore coding standards?

Comment: @AlexWayne: I don't understand JSHint as a tool, that states: "I know THE STANDARD". Coding style is configurable in JSHint and it helps to make the code consistent and to avoid errors. Can you give me a link to an "I am the standard" page, that tells me not to indent this way and also tells me the reasons not to do it? Maybe I'm missing something. I think, the errors above are because of a bug in JSHint, not because I'm violating a standard, JSHint tries to establish. Maybe it's not common, but that's not more important to me, than structure and fast readability.

Comment: @adeneo: I've read the "Comma First" rule a minute ago in the npm coding standards. I really don't like it. But I can see, that this is better, than putting the commas at the end. But I will not do it this way, because I don't like it - not because my solution is better. It is just a feeling biased by habit. And the advantage of putting the commas at the beginning is not so big, that I'm willing to change my habit. I think, it could be the same in your case. If not, please post any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion as a starting point; If you're not sure how to indent/space your code, paste it into a program that strips all whitespace(http://jscompress.com/) and take that and paste it into a formatting program(http://jsbeautifier.org/) and see how it comes out.

Your examples are output as such:

```
"use strict";
var foo = {
    bar: function () {}
};
foo.bar("a", {
    x: 1,
    y: 2
}, "b")
```

And

```
var webserviceRequest = webservice.createRequest();
webserviceRequest.addMethodRequest("GetFilterItems", {
    Start: start,
    NumItems: numItems
}, function (e) {
    e = syncItems(e);
    callback(e)
}).send()
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I would prefer my coding style because of two reasons: 1) I can see directly: Okay, `webservice.addMethodRequest()` is called with three parameters, because they are below each other with the same indentation (of course I use this only, if I can't write the parameters into one line). I don't have to read the whole thing and "parse" it. It is just clear by looking at it. 2) Also I can see, that the call chain to `webserviceRequest` is `addMethodRequest()`, `send()`, without having to "parse" the code. Maybe, it's about milliseconds to parse such a code. But what for?